# How to share embedded struct pointer

Tags: pointers, struct, go

I have following code:

A struct controller, that have anonymous fields.

```
type controller struct {
    *base.Controller
    store *data
}
```

As you can see, *base.Controller is anonymous fields pointer.
Then a second struct that composed with *base.Controller too.

```
type expiredError struct {
    *base.Controller
    local string
}
```

I initialized the controller struct as follow:

```
c := &controller{base.New(rw, r, false, "controller/account"), nil}
c.Title = "Activate account"
c.serve()
```

The base.Controller on controller is initialize with base.New() function.

Now I have on controller methods, that initialize the expiredError struct and it should share the pointer of base.Controller to base.Controller of expiredError too.

```
func (rcv *controller) validate() error {

    ....

    // If time for activating account is expired
    if time.Now().Unix() > rcv.store.Expired {
        // Delete registered user from neo4j
        maccount.Delete(rcv.store.Email, rcv.Local)

        return &expiredError{base.Controller, rcv.Local}
    }

    return nil
}
```

I've got here a compiler error

```
type base.Controller is not an expression
```

Comment: `type base.Controller is not an expression`, means you need an instance of something there, not the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try referencing the anonymous field by mentioning the instance of the parent class:

```
rcv.Controller
```

(since the "name" of an anonymous field is the same as the type of the field)

See a similar example in:

- "[Anonymous fields in structs - like object composition](http://golangtutorials.blogspot.fr/2011/06/anonymous-fields-in-structs-like-object.html)",
- "[Methods on structs](http://golangtutorials.blogspot.fr/2011/06/methods-on-structs.html)".

Comment: You can only access embedded fields by their type name, and type names can't have selectors. Only `rcv.Controller` could work.

Comment: @JimB indeed. I have edited the answer accordingly. I should have known since I used a similar example in http://stackoverflow.com/a/27733969/6309 yesterday.