# Understanding interfaces in Go

Tags: go

I am trying to understand how interfaces work in Go.

Let's say I have 2 structs:

```
package "Shape"

type Square struct {
   edgesCount int
}

type Triangle struct {
   edgesCount int
}
```

Now I create a `Shape` interface:

```
type Shape interface {

}
```

Why can't I specify that the `Shape` interface has an `egdesCount` property? Are interfaces only supposed to regroup methods?

Another problem I face is sharing function. Isn't possible to come up with something like this:

```
func New() *Shape {
  s:=new(Shape)
  s.edgesCount = 0
  return s
}
```

This would be much better than having to rewrite the exact same code:

```
func New() *Square {
  s:=new(Square)
  s.edgesCount = 0
  return s
}

func New() *Triangle {
  s:=new(Triangle)
  s.edgesCount = 0
  return s
}
```

(which also poses problem as I cannot redeclare my `New` function...)

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Note that Go also allows the terse alternative `type SquareEdges int`, for declaring types that have a single underlying data value. Everything else discussed here apples to these terse types too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are referring to isn't interface (which allows to pass an object as that interface, simply because the object is a receiver for all the interface method).
Here, an [empty `interface{}' Shape` would be satisfied by any type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23148998/6309), which isn't useful here.

It is more about [type embedding](http://www.hydrogen18.com/blog/golang-embedding.html) (using an [anonymous type structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28014640/6309) for instance):

That would *promote* the common field `edgesCount` to both struct.
As the [spec mentions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types):

> A field or method `f` of an anonymous field in a `struct x` is called **promoted** if `x.f` is a legal selector that denotes that field or method `f`.

See [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/7MQwSgumUx):

```
type Shape struct {
    edgesCount int
}

type Square struct {
    Shape
}

type Triangle struct {
    Shape
}

func NewSquare() *Square {
    return &Square{
        Shape{edgesCount: 4},
    }
}
func NewTriangle() *Triangle {
    return &Triangle{
        Shape{edgesCount: 3},
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Square %+v\n", NewSquare())
    fmt.Printf("Triangle %+v\n", NewTriangle())
}
```

Output:

```
Square &{Shape:{edgesCount:4}}
Triangle &{Shape:{edgesCount:3}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Go isn't an object oriented language, and those fields are internal fields since they start with lower case letters. Instead, try something like this:

```
type Shape interface {
    EdgeCount() int
}

type Square struct {
   edgesCount int
}

func (s Square) EdgeCount() int {
    return s.edgesCount
}

type Triangle struct {
   edgesCount int
}

func (t Triangle) EdgeCount() int {
    return t.edgesCount
}
```

Now you can do things using the EdgeCount function on either type of object since they both implement the Shape interface.

```
func IsItSquare(s Shape) bool {
    // If it has 4 sides, maybe
    return s.EdgeCount == 4
}
```

But you will still need to create the different types of shapes with independent New functions, or just by declaring them literally.

```
// Obviously a contrived example
s := Triangle{edgesCount: 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interface only group methods, as their purpose is to define behavior, very much like in other languages (see [Java Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html), for example).

What you are looking for is something like code inheritance, which doesn't exist in Go. BUT, you can get something similar with [struct embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding):

> Go does not provide the typical, type-driven notion of subclassing, but it does have the ability to “borrow” pieces of an implementation by embedding types within a struct or interface.

So, you can get what you want by doing the following ([play link](http://play.golang.org/p/jDoCl3yOIK)):

```
type Shape struct {
    edgeCount int
}

func (s Shape) EdgeCount() int {
    return s.edgeCount
}

type Square struct {
    Shape
}

type Triangle struct {
    Shape
}

func main() {
    sq := Square{Shape{edgeCount: 4}}
    tr := Square{Shape{edgeCount: 3}}
    fmt.Println(sq.EdgeCount())
    fmt.Println(tr.EdgeCount())
}
```